# Yeoman gulp-angular give error Eacces Permission denied

Tags: angularjs, npm, bower, yo, generator-gulp-angular

When I tried to install the application using `yo gulp-angular my-first-app`, it gives me error

```
Error :
return binding.open(pathModule._makeLog(path),stringtoFlag(flags),mode);
Eacces permission denied.
```

The full error stack has been attached as image from terminal .

I do not think I am doing some[image]thing wrong.

Comment: You did not have the permission to create the file bower.json. What is your OS?

Comment: OS X EL Captain V 10.11.4

Answer (score 1):

This problem is with the MAC OS X EL Captain. If you have not the permission to create a folder or file you need to give it explicitly.

Follow the below link for

```
https://support.apple.com/kb/PH22196?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US
```